# include bundle compiled with webpack to use in another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have the following structure of my app:

**index.js**

```
const app = require("./app")
exports.api = app(...)
```

**app.js**

```
//all the imports goes here
//and exporting the main function
module.exports = app => {...}
```

Now I need to bundle `app.js` with webpack but `index.js` must stay intact

The question is, after bundling the `app.js`, how can I `require` it's main function `app` from `index.js`?

After webpacking `app.js` I'm getting error in `index.js` that says "app is not a function" which makes sense since app.js content is now wrapped in webpack staff.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "app" bundle needs to be exported as a [commonjs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment).

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'app',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  }
};
```

> The return value of your entry point will be assigned to the exports object using the output.library value. As the name implies, this is used in CommonJS environments.

So, in your `index.js` you can `require('./dist/bundle-name.js')`.

Comment: thanks for the input! Could you please elaborate on what should be in the index.js to make use of it? I tried to import it in different ways but can't make it work so far (it's for nodejs).

Comment: Whatever is exported in app.js will be available as "MyLibrary", read the docs.

Comment: I did read the docs, not much help there unless I'm reading it wrong. Can you show an example on how you'll import it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, pay attention that I've changed the `libraryTraget`

Comment: Thanks @felixmosh, this is working now! The only thing to mention is that webpack creates a named import at the root and in this case the import goes like this: require('./dist/bundle-name.js').app (or whatever the "library" name is in the config)

Answer (score 1):

seems to be a hack, but I made it work by adding an intermediate file and adjusting `app.js` and `index.js` like below:

**index.js**

```
const app = require("./bundle").app //changed to named import
exports.api = app(...)
```

**bundle.js** //an intermediate file which is now an entry point for webpack

```
import app from "./app"
exports.app = app
```

**app.js**

```
//all the imports goes here
//and exporting the main function
export default app => {...} //changed to default export
```

If anyone has explanation on why it works this way and how to simplify it without adding that `bundle.js` file, you are very welcome to comment!